# How to creat a mecha style mesh for character?

Tags: mesh

I try to creat a mesh look like following pics. I want to make a torso for my character.
Please give me some tips or tutorials?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should study and use:

- extrude (E key)
- move edges and vertexes (G key)
- fill faces (F key)
- inset (i key)

Comment: The basic hot key I had know to use. But I mean if want to create a mecha style mesh, I dont know how to start. Just like you have tools but dont know how to make a car.

Comment: Follow a youtube tutorial to learn how to do stuff, for example: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U or https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn3ukorJv4vs_eSJUQPxBRaDS8PrVmIri or https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn3ukorJv4vvv3ZpWJYvV5Tmvo7ISO-NN or https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3UWN2F2M2C8-zUjbFlbgtWPQa0NXBsp0

Comment: Thx Sanbaldo~~~ These videos are helpful. I will check them later. Thx again.